# Force OWIN Google Auth middleware to use SSL redirect URL

Tags: ssl, google-oauth, owin, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm using the UseGoogleAuthentication OWIN middleware to integrate google auth with Thinktecture IdentityServer but the redirect URI that's getting passed to google is not using HTTPS.

I think it's because the SSL is being termiated at my load balancer and the last hop between the load balancer and the server is plain HTTP but I can't see any options that let me override the redirect URL.

When the redirect finally times out I can simply modify the URL in the browser to add HTTPS: and the sign in works so everything else seems okay.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158495/change-facebook-redirect-uri-web-api/34191701?noredirect=1#comment56199670_34191701

Comment: That doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I tell a lie, it worked like a charm. The reason it didn't work first time is because I wasn't using the correct IAppBuilder instance as my OWIN app is partitioned up into a few different areas.