# ASP.NET Owin OAuth callback URL with reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nginx, oauth

I need your help to solve an issue i have with OAuth on my MVC5 application. On my development environment everything's fine. I set up Twitter/Google/Facebook/Microsoft providers and it works like a charm for now.

My issue is on a test environment. I'm using nGinx as a front server to holds the certificates and serves some static content through a subdirectory of the domain.
The proxy part is configured as followed :

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
```

The problem is that all my configured callback URLs for external providers are on the HTTPS scheme but running the application on HTTP makes the callback url having an HTTP protocol (for example, the authorized callback URL is https://example.com/signin-facebook but the effective callback URL sent to provider is http://example.com/signin-facebook).

I saw on other posts that there is a AspNetCore solution with UseForwardedHeaders but as i'm still on normal AspNet, it's not an option.

As a dirty workaround, i temporarly allowed URLs with an HTTP protocol as callback URLs for Twitter/Facebook and Google but Microsoft is strict and only allow HTTPS (This workaround works because my nGinx is configured to perform a 301 Redirect on incoming HTTP requests to the same request over HTTPS)

Does anyone have a solution to change the scheme of the base URL used to build the callback URL ?

Comment: Did you read this article: https://www.nginx.com/blog/authenticating-users-existing-applications-openid-connect-nginx-plus/

Comment: @TejSoft : Thanks for the link ! First, paying 2500$/y to use nGinx Plus is not an option. It's a personal project and i won't earn money with it to afford that. Second, i'm looking for a way to modify the scheme of the redirect_uri built in the Owin context as the context is HTTP but is not publicly available and should be HTTPS to be reachable from outside. It seems possible in AspNetCore (with the UseForwardedHeaders) and i'm looking for something similar in AspNet. For now switching to AspNetCore is not yet an option...

Comment: If someone as noob as me is looking for a solution i ended with a solution thanks to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158495/change-facebook-redirect-uri-web-api